# Retrieve map objects from map after migrating from Premium to Navigate edition

Tags: android, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

Previously in the Premium edition you could retrieve all objects on the map via `map.allMapObjects` but now in the Navigate edition there seems to be no way to do this. All you can do is add and remove objects to/from a scene. Does this mean I have to keep instances of all added map objects around and keep track of them instead of retrieving them from the map via a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. As of now (HERE SDK 4.13.5), for most map items, you need to remember what instances you have added.

At least, for `MapMarkers`, you can remove a list of markers:

```
mapView.getMapScene().removeMapMarkers(mapMarkerList);
```